# Additional/extended code analysis rules

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, static-analysis

I recently set up the static analysis in VS2010 for one of my hobby projects (and annotated all headers), and some of the suggestions it made helped track down a few annoying little bugs.

Seeing that, I've been curious as to whether there is a more extensive rule set around or if such things are available anywhere (I'm using the "Microsoft All Rules" at the moment).

Are there additional rule sets that I could use; if so, where? (Google didn't find any easily)

If not (or even if there are), is there a better set to use? (my project works with graphics mostly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written about 8, and may be writing more soon, if any of [these](http://imaginarydevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/09/vs2010-code-analysis-custom-rules.html) interest you let me know.

Team policy reminder/enforcers

- warn on calls to forbidden methods

  - GC.Collect GC.AddMemoryPressure
  - Messagebox.Show
- warn if inheriting directly from Windows.Forms or Windows.Control
- warn if a control or form subclass constructor does not call InitializeComponent()
- warn if a control property is not set per team standards

  - DialogBorderStyle must be fixed
- error if you do not override certain virtual properties (legacy from vs2005 designer bug)
- error if you have code that raises a NotImplementedException
- warn if you don't have hungarian notation to name controls
- warn if fields are not private
- ensure a project does not call a Config value or index that does not exist.

Also some of the code is found [here](http://ideone.com/kZp64)

Comment: Alas, your rules themselves aren't much use to me, as I primarily do C++. However, the fact that this is possible and has been done (and I might be able to do some of my own), very much does. I'll be looking at your code snippet to see what I can make of it; do you happen to have any more info around? Thanks for this, though, first evidence I've seen.

Comment: I would think based on the way these are written that they would work with c++.

Comment: Thanks, I'll play with it and might send a question or two your way sometime (if you don't mind terribly). :)